# How do I make my Datepicker work?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

My datepicker doesn't work.
I have searched many questions that were similar to mine.
But I still couldn't find the solution.
I've only pasted the code that I think has some problems.
Here is my code in aspx:
It is in the script.

```
$(function () {
        init();
    });

     function init() {
        if (typeof $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidDepartDate").val() !== "undefined") {
            var _dateStr = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidDepartDate").val().substring(0, $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidDepartDate").val().length - 1);
            var _dateStrArray = _dateStr.split(",");
        }

        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {


                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

                return [_dateStrArray.indexOf(string) >= 0];
            },
            onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
                ChangeHiddenRadioButtonSelected(CTypeToDateString(selected));
            },
            inline: true
        });

    }

    function CTypeToDateString(selected) {
        var tempTime = selected.split("/");
        var year = tempTime[2];
        var month = tempTime[0];
        var day = tempTime[1];
        var yyyymmdd = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
        return yyyymmdd;
    }

    function ChangeHiddenRadioButtonSelected(SelectDate) {

        var _dateCount = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidDepartCount").val();
         //alert(_dateCount);
        var ServerDate = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(_dateCount); i++) {

            ServerDate = $('label[for="ContentPlaceHolder1_rblDepartDate_' + i + '"]').html().substring(0, 10);

            if (ServerDate == SelectDate) {
                var radioItem = $('input[id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rblDepartDate_' + i + '"]');
                if (radioItem) {
                    if (typeof $('input[id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rblDepartDate_' + i + '"]').attr("onclick") !== "undefined") {
                        if ($('input[id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rblDepartDate_' + i + '"]').attr("onclick").indexOf("no1") >= 0) {
                            alert('no2');
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            $('input[id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rblDepartDate_' + i + '"]').prop("checked", true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('input[id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rblDepartDate_' + i + '"]').prop("checked", true);
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(init);
```

There are all in the

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
```

The code of datepicker is

```
 <div runat="server" id="datepicker"></div>
```

The pass from cs :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, this.GetType(), "bind", "init();", true);
```

I believe the problem is probably in this code.
Please help me.

Comment: Did you include jQuery UI as well, and did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Yes,I include jQuery UI surely.I can't check the console beacuse I didn't have the project file.Only got the dll file.

Comment: @徐尉庭 open the debug mode(in chrome press F12) then switch to console tab and see if there is any exception.

Comment: Okay,II'll give it a try.
Does my code have any wrong?

Comment: @蕭為元 the console tab didn't display anything.

Comment: I've found the solution!
I change my version of .NET framework.
It works.